# How to add and remove searchBar from navigationItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am having trouble adding and removing a UISearchControllers searchBar to a UINavigationBar.

Here is what I am doing:

**Add the searchBar to the view**

```
searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleProminent;
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

[searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:searchController.searchBar];
```

**On button click add the searchBar to the navigationItem**
This works as expected

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:false];
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
```

**And here is where I am getting the strange behaviour:**

**On another button click remove the searchBar from the nav bar and add it back to the view**

```
[searchController.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:true];
[self.view addSubview:searchController.searchBar];

[searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
```

The searchBar is removed from the Nav Bar as expected, but it is not returned to the main view. ( well i can't see it anywhere)

I log the value of the search bar I can see that it has the frame that I have given it.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set `navigationItem .titleView` to `nil` first and `setFrame:` in main thread.

```
- (IBAction)addBar:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
    [searchController.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

- (IBAction)removeBar:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
    [searchController.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:searchController.searchBar];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self->searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, self->searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
    });
}
```

By the way, I think it is better that put the search bar in a wrapper `UIView` when adding to the `navigationItem.titleView`.